# cakephp Router::connect with no layout?

Tags: cakephp

I have this line on routes.php in cakephp1.3

```
Router::connect('/successful/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'login_successful'));
```

I do not want to use a layout at all, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible unless you create an action in the pages controller and use `$this->layout = emptylayout` in that action where `emptylayout` would only contain `<?php echo $content_for_layout ?>`

Comment: You can set public $layout = "bare" in the controller, layout selection is better not part of the action.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the layout to an empty string

```
$this->layout = '';
```